# Trying to show $\mathcal S(\Bbb R)\subset L^p(\Bbb R)\ \forall 1\leq p\leq\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces, schwartz-space

$$\mathcal S(\Bbb R):=\big\{f:\Bbb R\mapsto\Bbb R\ :\ \forall k,l\in\Bbb N \  \sup\limits_{x\in\Bbb R}\{|x^k|\cdot|f^{(l)}(x)|\}<\infty\big\}$$

I am trying to show that $\mathcal S(\Bbb R)\subset L^p(\Bbb R)$ for any $p\in[1,\infty]$

First if $p=\infty$ then $\|f\|_{\infty}=\sup\limits_{t\in\Bbb R}|f(t)|<\infty$ by taking $k=0,\ l=0$ in the definition.

If $p\in[1,\infty)$

I would like to prove something pretty strong: If $f\in\mathcal S(\Bbb R)$ then for any $\epsilon>0\ \exists q\in\Bbb R$ s.t. $$\int\limits_{-\infty}^{-q}|f(x)|dx+\int\limits_{q}^{+\infty}|f(x)|dx<\epsilon$$ that will be stronger than what's necessary but I think it is true for functions in $\mathcal S(\Bbb R)$. In fact those function go to zero really fast as $|x|\rightarrow\infty$, faster than any polynomial (I'm pretty sure).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: choose for a fixed $p$ an integer $k$ such that the function $t\mapsto \left(1+\left\lvert t\right\vert^k\right)^{-1}$ belongs to $\mathbb L^p$ and observe that 
$$\left\lvert f(t)\right\rvert^{p}\leqslant\left(1+\left\lvert t\right\vert^k\right)^{-p}\left(
\sup_{x\in\mathbb R}\left(1+\left\lvert x\right\vert^k\right)\left\lvert f(x)\right\rvert\right)^{p}.$$

Comment: And how did you choose the function $(1+|t|^k)^{-1}$ ?

Comment: One could this about $t^{-k}$ but there would be a problem at $0$ for integrability.